Mulesoft connection Issue - Marketing cloud
We are tyring to authenticate Marketing cloud SOAP api using Marketing cloud connector. The test connection is successful when on public network. But, when on VPN, test connection is failing with below error :
Test connection failed :unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Please help me establish connection successfully.
Anypoint Configuration

That seems to be a problem of the security of your VPN or your company. Probably something in your security infrastructure is intercepting certificates from the TLS traffic and modifying them, like deep TLS introspection. There is nothing we can do. Talk to the people that administer your VPN.
